# How to scrape full of review page in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I actually know how to do it, but I wondering is it possible with minimum coding effort. How to scrape full of review page if not all of it is shown.

The website is [here](https://www.sikayetvar.com/turkcell). It's about customer complaints over the turkcell gsm operator. My code shown below:

```
library(rvest); library(tidyverse)
url <- "https://www.sikayetvar.com/turkcell"
reviews <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes("a.complaint-link-for-ads") %>% 
  html_text()

reviews <- textclean::replace_non_ascii(reviews) #turkish characters
reviews <- tolower(reviews)
reviews <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","",reviews)
reviews <- gsub(" ","-",reviews)
reviews <- stringr::str_c(url,"/",reviews)

get_reviews <- function(master_df){
  as.data.frame(
    read_html(master_df) %>% 
      html_nodes("div.description") %>% 
      html_text()
  )
}

reviews_full <- reviews %>% 
  map(get_reviews) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  as_tibble()

colnames(reviews_full) <- "reviews"
reviews_full <- as_tibble(gsub('\\n+','',reviews_full$reviews))

reviews_full[1:2,]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, is this code working and you want a code review?

Comment: Yes, it's working but I want to write minimum code if possible. @QHarr

Comment: perhaps consider code review site

Comment: I guess I couldn't tell myself. No problem. The page has customer comments and not showing full of them. Some pages have 'continue reading' or 'read more', you know. In this case how to get full of customer comments in R?